# Pop Over Control on iPad Problem !

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk

i try to load a view via UIPopover but my app crash after tap the popover button , i tried to solve it but i don't understand ! here is my code :

-

```
(IBAction)calendarPopUp:(id)sender {

 PopViewController *cal = [[PopViewController alloc]init];
//The compiler tells me the problem comes from this line :
 UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:cal];
 [popOver setDelegate:self];
 [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(113, 64, 226, 129) inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
 [popOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(226, 129)];
}
```

Comment: chek the pic : http://freezpic.com/pics/86557c8767416ca5242b6714d740a799.png

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should change `inView:self` to `inView:self.view`.